# Frequency of neutron versus gamma emission by a radioactive source

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, neutrons, gamma-rays

Given gamma and neutron emission spectra for a radioactive source, say PuBe-239 for example, is there a way to calculate what fraction of total particles emitted are neutrons or gammas? If not, what's a good ballpark estimate? 99% are gammas, 1% neutrons?

Comment: The branching ratios are experimentally determined. Such ratios can help in determining the nuclear structure. The Evaluated Nuclear Structure data site (http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) is a good place to start.

Comment: I imagine it would depend on the proportions of Pu to Be, and on the amount of material and even the geometry. Presumably the people designing these sources fiddle with these parameters in order to achieve the desired neutron flux with a minimum amount of 239Pu, which is not something you want people buying and selling in quantity, due to worries about the proliferation of nuclear weapons.

Comment: @JonCuster: I don't think there's a branching ratio that's relevant. 239Pu decays entirely through alpha decay to 235U, which has a much longer half-life. The alphas hit the beryllium and produce neutrons, so what matters is stuff like the cross-section for the $\alpha$+Be reaction. (It's possible that the gamma decay of the 235U daughter proceeds through more than one pathway, in which case there would be gamma branching ratios that would be relevant.)

Comment: @BenCrowell - well, there are Be9($\alpha$,$\alpha$)Be9 resonances as well to consider, and both ($\alpha$,n) and ($\alpha$,$\alpha$) look like the there are a variety of gammas possible from excited nuclear states. In the general case, going to the nuclear structure data is the best thing to do.

Comment: @JonCuster: Are you talking about gammas emitted by 9Be? I'm sure those exist, but they come about only when an alpha particle comes close enough to a 9Be nucleus to excite it. I would expect that to be a low-probability process. Its probability will depend on the cross-section and on geometrical factors and so on. But emission of gammas by the 235U daughters is a process that occurs with a pretty high probability, of order unity. (Looking at ENSDF for 235U, it looks like there is, for example, a 52 keV gamma emitted with probability $\sim0.1$.)

Comment: My point is basically that this is more of a cross-section thing than a branching-ratio thing. When a 239Pu decays, the probability of getting a gamma is of order unity, while the probability of getting a neutron from an interaction with 9Be is, I would imagine, many orders of magnitude lower, and depends on cross-sections and geometry.

Comment: @BenCrowell - and the probability of which gamma is emitted with the neutron from the C-13 nucleus varies with incident alpha energy. See for example Phys. Rev. 102(5) 1348 (1956) - Neutrons and Gamma Rays from the Alpha-Particle Bombardment of Be9, B10, B11, C13, and O18 by T.W. Bonner et al. (yes, the APS Bonner prize).

Answer (score 0):

The [Particle Data Group's reference page about common radioactive sources](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2017-rev-commonly-used-radioactive-sources.pdf) gives

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{source} &
\text{particle} & \text{energy (MeV)} & \text{branching fraction}
\\\hline
\rm^{241}Am
& \alpha & 5.443 & 13\% \\
& \alpha & 5.486 & 84\% \\
& \gamma & 0.060 & 36\% \\
& \text{Np x-rays} & & 38\% \\
\hline
\rm^{241}Am/Be
& \rm n & \sim4\rm\,MeV & 60\times10^{-6} \\
& \gamma & 4.43 & 40\times10^{-6} \\
\end{array}
$$

Apparently, some (but not all) of the americium alpha decays are accompanied by a gamma-ray cascade, but the most intense of those gamma rays is relatively low energy. In an AmBe source, the cross section for the $\rm^{9}Be(\alpha,n)2\alpha$ reaction is about about twice as high for the branch of that reaction with an associated gamma as for the branch without the associated gamma, and those gamma rays are much higher-energy than the primary gamma rays from the americium decay.  However, both cross sections are very small.

So from  a sealed AmBe source (which doesn't allow the primary alpha particles to escape), nearly all of the radiation particles will be low-energy gamma rays and x-rays, but the higher-energy gamma rays and the neutrons will be about equally common.  A PuBe source will behave in broadly the same way.

(I know people who have used the 4 MeV photons from a PuBe or AmBe source as "triggers" to tell a data acquisition system to look for a neutron.)